# Kotlin getParcelableArray from intent bundle not able to cast it to custom type

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, bundle, classcastexception

I am running into a weird problem . I have a class A which implements Parcelable interface in kotlin.

I am passing the array of class A from one activity to another no issues here.

```
 var arrayOfA:Array<A> // just to tell the type assume the array is initialised with the value
 intent.putExtra("array", arrayOfA)
```

But while receiving it in another activity , I am not able to assign it to variable of type Array it is asking me to assign it to Array when A is on type parcelable why I am not able to assign it the variable.

```
in second Activity 
var arrayOfA:Array<A>?=null


arrayA=intent.get("array") as Array<A> // Problem here. Class cast exception
```

I am not able to understand why. Can some one help me here. I don't want to change the type of variable to Array as it as many inter depedencies.(The class here is just a demonstration)

========================================

```
class A(val a:String?,val b:String?):Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString()) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(a)
        parcel.writeString(b)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<A> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): A {
            return A(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<A?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to add class A to the question. Without it it's very hard to answer

Comment: Please see edit

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same problem. This is how I was able to workaround it:

`arrayOfA = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("array").map { it as A }.toTypedArray()`

For some reason this does not work:

`arrayOfA = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("array") as Array<A>`

That unfortunately exhibits a warning

> Unchecked cast: Array<(out) Parcelable!>! to Array)

and runtime exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast
>   to com.company.app.A[]

Comment: But why is this happening do you know @JordanH?

Answer (score 8):

`Bundle.getParcelableArray` (and `Intent.getParcelableArrayExtra`) return `Parcelable[]`. You can't cast `Parcelable[]` as `MyClass[]`. You can cast an *element* of `Parcelable[]` as `MyClass`.

Use `Bundle.getParcelableArrayList` (or its `Intent` counterpart) instead, because it has a generic type.

```
var values: List<MyClass> = listOf(...)
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", values.asArrayList())
values = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("key")!!

fun <E> List<E>.asArrayList(): ArrayList<E> = this as? ArrayList<E> ?: ArrayList(this)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `getParcelableArrayExtra` to retrieve `Parcelable` objects as in

```
arrayA = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("array") as Array<A?>
```

Make `class A` as `Nullable` all over, because you can't cast `Nullable` to `Non Nullable` in Kotlin

creator should be like below

```
companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<A?> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): A? {
            return A(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<A?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even If I do it , I am getting classcastexpection. Cannot case Parcelable[] to A[]

Comment: could you paste your stack trace?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to A[]

Comment: let me try this and let you know